# Computed column slows down query performance in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012, calculated-columns

In my `select` statement, the column `DisplayStatus` is a computed column that significantly slows down the performance.

I tried to make it `PERSISTENT` but it tells me that table need to be dropped and recreated again. I cannot do that, I am not the owner of those tables.

Scalar function (pretty complex) is responsible for computed column.

My `select` statement:

```
declare
    @EffDateFrom datetime ='2017-02-01',
    @EffDateTo   datetime ='2017-08-28'

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Data') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Data 

CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    QuoteID int NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Submitted] [int] NULL,
    [Quoted] [int] NULL,
    [Bound] [int] NULL,
    [Exonerated] [int] NULL,
    [ProducerLocationId] [int] NULL,
    [ProducerName] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [BusinessType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DisplayStatus] [varchar](50) NULL, --This is the problem
    [Agent] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [ProducerContactGuid] uniqueidentifier NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Data
    SELECT 
        tblQuotes.QuoteID,
        tblQuotes.EffectiveDate,
        CASE 
           WHEN lstQuoteStatus.QuoteStatusID >= 1   
              THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
        END AS Submitted,
        CASE 
           WHEN lstQuoteStatus.QuoteStatusID = 2 OR 
                lstQuoteStatus.QuoteStatusID = 3 OR 
                lstQuoteStatus.QuoteStatusID = 202 
              THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
        END AS Quoted,
        CASE WHEN lstQuoteStatus.Bound = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Bound,
        CASE WHEN lstQuoteStatus.QuoteStatusID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Exonareted,
        tblQuotes.ProducerLocationID,
        P.Name + ' / '+ P.City as [ProducerName], 
        CASE 
           WHEN tblQuotes.PolicyTypeID = 1 THEN 'New Business' 
           WHEN tblQuotes.PolicyTypeID = 3 THEN 'Rewrite'
        END AS BusinessType,
        tblQuotes.DisplayStatus, -------------This is the problem
        tblProducerContacts.FName +' '+ tblProducerContacts.LName as Agent,
        tblProducerContacts.ProducerContactGUID
    FROM    
        tblQuotes 
    INNER JOIN 
        lstQuoteStatus ON tblQuotes.QuoteStatusID = lstQuoteStatus.QuoteStatusID 
    INNER JOIN 
        tblProducerLocations P ON P.ProducerLocationID = tblQuotes.ProducerLocationID
    INNER JOIN 
        tblProducerContacts ON dbo.tblQuotes.ProducerContactGuid = tblProducerContacts.ProducerContactGUID
    WHERE   
        tblQuotes.EffectiveDate >= @EffDateFrom 
        AND tblQuotes.EffectiveDate <= @EffDateTo
        AND dbo.tblQuotes.LineGUID = '6E00868B-FFC3-4CA0-876F-CC258F1ED22D'--Surety
        AND tblQuotes.OriginalQuoteGUID IS NULL

SELECT * FROM #Data
```

Is any other workaround to bring this column without slowing down the performance?

Execution Plan:

[image]

Comment: What's the computation of DisplayStatus?  If you comment it out of the insert, does the query perform better?

Comment: Yes. Much better. Further in my SP based on that status I am calculating number of "Cancelled" policies. So I need this `DisplayStatus` column

Comment: I would get with the owner of the table.  It sounds like the function needs to be tuned.  I don't think you can tune the query as stated here.  I'd  run a simple query that only returned DisplayStatus from tblQuotes for the number of rows expected in the given statement.  This would give you something to show the table owner.

Comment: Did you look at the execution plan? Show us.

Comment: Added execution plan

Comment: "Scalar function (pretty complex) is responsible for computed column." There you go. Scalar-valued functions are the Great Satan of performance killers. (The [Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273443/) for this is still going strong after 10 years.) Try factoring out the calculation to an inline table-valued function and `CROSS APPLY` that. For anything more than a single call, scalar-valued functions just straight up suck.